# autohotkey script cannot detect second image search

Tags: autohotkey

i am still a newbie at this but i want to make it work.
I want the program to check both up and down and give me a result, but the result is always the same even when it shouldn't be.

This is the code i have now.

```
stop:=0
one:=0
two:=0

while(stop<1)
{

ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 270, 270, 380, 330, *5 G:\image.png
if !errorlevel
{
one=1
}

ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 270, 790, 380, 850, *5 G:\image.png
if !errorlevel
{
two++
}

sleep 500 ;wait for result to load

if (one=1) && (two=1)
{
stop = 2
msgbox, found up and down
exitapp
}
else if (one=1) && (two=0)
{
msgbox, found only up
}
else if (one=0) && (two=1)
{
msgbox, found only down
} ;end if
} ;end while
```

I am only getting the result "found up only" when i should be getting "found up and down".
I think it is because the second image search does not actually go through and work when it should, any links to possible fixes will be appriciated!

Comment: Is two incrementing correctly?

Comment: I recoded everything, it works now. The problem was on `while`. when i used `while` it wouldn't work but when i used `loop` it worked. If you want to exit a `loop` type `break`